# Using data local messed up the data sorting in jqGrid grouping

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am using jqGrid grouping with data local.
My data is already sorted, so I just want to display it according to the order of my data array. However, I noticed that jqGrid actually changes the order of my data when I use grouping.
I can reproduce this issue in this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/PTziE7HXR1QEzkU3JHdU?p=preview). The order of data should be `1 2 3 4 5 6` but instead it is displaying `1 2 4 5 6 3`

I am using jqGrid 4.6.0 currently. Currently the workaround that I can think is adding a hidden column called "rankOrder" and then on `loadComplete`, sort the column based on rankOrder. I have multiple tables in my application so I want to avoid doing that (adding hidden column to each table). Anybody knows better workaround of this?

UPDATE:
I noticed this also happens with **free jqGrid 4.8.0,** here's a working demo created by user Oleg, and I forked it to reproduce my issue [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6zhhkbv6/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve the problem of **sorting of the first page during initial loading of local data** by replacing `data: myData, datatype: "local"` with `datastr: myData, datatype: "jsonstring"`. On the other side you use *local paging* of data. To display the next page of data jqGrid have to sort the data to get the next page.

Thus I suppose that you need just add `sortname: "OrderID"` option to the grid to solve your problem and to display the data grouped by `CustomerID` *and sorted* by `OrderID` additionally. You should stay by original `data: myData, datatype: "local"`. I recommend you to add `sorttype: "integer"` in the `OrderID` to have `10` after `9` and not between `1` and `2` during sorting.

Comment: thanks again as usual :) just a question why does it not preserving the order of the data when grouping is enabled? this problem does not happen when grouping is not enabled (it preserves the order of data)

Comment: @blenzcoffee: You are welcome! Probably I cleared not good enough in my answer. The implementation of *local grouping* means that soring will be *always made* before displaying the page. If you use grouping only then the sorting will be done *by one column only*. It can change the original order of rows. By including additional `sortname: "OrderID"`the sorting will be **by two columns**: grouping column and `sortname`. If you have multiple rows where the values for both columns are the same then the order can still be changed.